# In Excel, how to multiply ranges

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to know how to multiply one range of cells (say A1:F10) by another range of cells (static range say H1:M10) then put the answer in one cell only (say Cell P1) .... then move down one row and multiply the new range (say A2:F11) by the same static range (say H1:M10) then put the answer in the cell below the first answer (say P2) and so on....

When multiplying I need A1 to multiply by H1, B1 multiplied by I1, A2 multiplied by H2 and so on...

I have no clue, please thank you for your help... For info my range is a range of 2800 cells by 2800 cells so fairly large. Is there a way of doing this in Excel or do I need to use VB? thank you so much...

Comment: How do you convert so many multiplications in to one cell?

Comment: Can you give some examples? Do you mean you would like to multiply the value in one cell in a range with a value in another cell in another range, and that for every cell in both ranges?

Comment: Add this function to a cell =A1*H1, If this is not the answer, please make your question more clear!

Comment: Thank you Sir, I must apologies I had completely forgotten this query, thanks you again

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sumproduct for that. Use a relative reference for the first range and an absolute reference for the second range.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell P1 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:F10*$H$1:$M$10)
```

Copy down. In cell P2 it will change to

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:F11*$H$1:$M$10)
```

and so on, incrementing the rows of the first range in each row. The second range is fixed to H1 to M1 with the $ signs and will not change when copied down.